# Tweaking WIN10 (2019) File Explorer's file size: filter thresholds. (how can we do this?)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows File Explorer you can type **size:** into the search box, and it will offer 7 predefined size-ranges empty/tiny/small/medium/large/huge/gigantic

For the longest time "gigantic" was set as **>128mb**
This was useful, you could quickly find all movie files in a folder tree.

Recently (some 2018/2019 update), Microsoft decided to modernise the definitions of these 7 predefined size-ranges so that:

- Large (128MB - 1GB)
- Huge (1GB - 4GB)
- Gigantic (> 4GB)

... ok that is a more 'modern' definition, but now the **size:** search function becomes less useful to me.   Now my movie files are fragmented between 3 different search results!!

Question:
Does anyone know a registry key which can be used to manipulate the thresholds of the **size:** search filter in file explorer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Windows definition of what a "gigantic" file is](https://superuser.com/q/501920/241386)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other posts with this question but haven't seen a way to modify those thresholds.
But **Serach** does allow you to use expressions as well as the pre-defined ranges. If you type: **size:>128MB** in the **Search** box, you will get all files in a single result.

Keith

Comment: Confirmed!  Thank you, I genuinely learned something useful today!

Comment: You're welcome!  Can I get an up-vote???  :D